# Apple push notification - one message received but 2+ alerts

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, azure, push-notification

when i push a notification to ios device, one message is received but alert pops up 2+ times. (ios 7+)when notification pushed to android device, everything is normal. 1 message received, 1 alert.

```
environment: 
backend - azure notification hubs
frontend - (AppBuilder) cordova.js + angularjs
```

checked registrations on azure, no duplicate device token, i.e. every registration has a unique device token.any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: It's sending form server. Please check on server also ..

Comment: where do you implement alert code in your delegate class. check that its calling two times or what.? and put also code that you are implemented in to you project for push notification.

Comment: Please check with the delegate method calling how many times in app delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem fixed. duplicate registrations with same device id in azure notification hubs.